# How to upload project into appfactory preview?

Tags: wso2

I'm testing with wso2 appfactory. Since it's not ready to run at local server I would like to test POC with preview edition. How can I upload a sample project into appfactory online edition?
How to populate database with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own project and using GIT commands you can checkout it in to your local machine.
Then open it using dev studio and do the code changes and commit it using dev studio or GIT.

Following blog posts might help you.

For [GIT commands](http://ushanib.blogspot.com/2013/02/steps-to-checkout-and-commit-wso2.html)
For [Dev Studio](http://manisha-eleperuma.blogspot.com/2013/07/create-artifacts-for-wso2-app-factory.html)

Comment: Hi Ushani, Just curious, at this point, does appfactory only support CAR files? (only carbon projects?)

Comment: At this point AF does not support CAR files. Supports only WAR, JAXRS, JAXWS, Dataservice, BPEL and Jaggery. But CAR,PHP and ESB will be available in upcoming releases since its in the upcoming feature list

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create an application](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AF100/Take+a+Quick+Tour) and do the modifications in the code repository.

Please refer [WSO2 App Factory User Guide](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AF100/User+Guide) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

App Factory is graduated from preview, and WSO2 App Cloud is now available here: http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud/

There are a few ways you can upload applications into [WSO2 App Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud/):

- [Via GIT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AppCloud/Create+an+Application+with+my+Source+Code),
- [As WAR file](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AppCloud/Create+an+Application+with+an+Archive+File),
- [From Dev Studio](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AppCloud/Use+WSO2+Developer+Studio+to+Develop%2C+Build+and+Deploy+Applications).